# Why not warn the Law Council earlier?

Tags: dc, superman, dc-extended-universe, man-of-steel

Why didn't [Jor-El](http://dccomicsextendeduniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Jor-El) warn the council earlier that Krypton was doomed?

Comment: AFAIR, he did, and nobody believed him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The film transcript would strongly imply that he *had* spoken to them about it before, at sufficient length for the Council to spend their time looking at each other and rolling their eyes during his latest speech.

> **[Jor-El:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PsNjYQMPA1o)** *We may only have a matter of weeks. **I warned you.** Harvesting the core
>   was suicide. It has accelerated the process of implosion.*

It would seem that Jor-El was ignored, and continues to be ignored because his tedious doom-mongering speeches about how they're going to '***kill the world***' are long on apocalyptic warnings and very short on *actual solutions* to the energy crisis. His only suggestion is to reactivate the lost colonies (dumb) and to try to evacuate as many people as possible (basically a recipe for civil unrest, riots and the end of civilisation as they know it).

---

The film's [official novelisation](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/16113771-man-of-steel) is in broad agreement.

> Council Member Lor-Em, seated to the right of Ro-Zar, **waved away Jor-El’s impassioned declarations.**
>   “Our energy reserves were exhausted,” he replied. “What would you have us do?”
>   “Reach out to the stars... like our ancestors did.” Jor-El tried to get through to the Council members, all of whom had inherited their positions by virtue of genetic heritage. **Like too many Kryptonians, they seemed more concerned with preserving the status quo—and their comfortable lifestyles—than worrying about the future.** “There are other habitable worlds within reach. We can use the old outposts—”
>   “Are you seriously suggesting we evacuate the entire planet?” **Ro-Zar scoffed at the notion.**